# const reference binding to an rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

Working on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304680) question, I found an inconsistent behavior.

Why reference binding behave different in a constructor from a common function?

```
struct A {
};

struct B : public A {
  B(){}
private:
  B(const B&);
};

void f( const B& b ) {}

int main() {
  A a( B() ); // works
  A const & a2 = B(); // C++0x: works, C++03: fails
  f( B() );  // C++0x: works, C++03: fails
}
```

I have tested it for C++03 with g++-4.1 and Comeau 4.2.45.2 in strict C++03 mode and with C++0x extensions disabled. I got same results.

For C++0x was tested with g++-4.4 and Comeau 4.3.9 in relaxed mode and with C++0x extensions enabled. I got same results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
A a(B());
```

is the declaration of a function named a returning an A and taking a pointer to a function without argument returning a B.  See
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300327/sort-function-does-not-work-with-function-object-created-on-stack/1300346#1300346).
Add parenthesis and you'll get the error you expect:

```
A a((B()));
```

Comment: Famously known as "the most vexing parse".

Comment: I can't wait for the day when I could say to someone "you fell victim to the most vexing parse problem". Of course by the time that happens I'll completely forget about it and return to hating C++.